# Using sp_executesql without returning row sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

In a store procedure I am building dynamic SQL statement which is executed using `sp_executesql` procedure.

The dynamic SQL statement can be a store procedure, that:

- do not return row set
- do return one row set
- do return multiple row sets

The initial store procedure itself returns other row sets. I want to return only them, and to not return the row sets from the internal procedure.

Generally, I want to force the following statement to do not return anything:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DynamicSQLStatement = N'SELECT 1 SELECT 2 SELECT 3 SELECT 4 SELECT 5'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatement
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you have to use Dynamic SQL and it is returning one, none or multiple result sets , and giving you the expected result sets, Why you want to change it ?????

Comment: Because the `Dynamic SQL` should do something like `INSERT` records, but I do not need to show its internal messages like `All records are inserted` or  `List with inserted records`

Comment: Oh, if it's just about suppressing the `n row(s) affected` messages then `SET NOCOUNT ON` is your friend.

Comment: No, not this message. Image a procedure that insert some records in a table and returns two row sets - one with status 'OK'/'Not ok' and second that listed all inserted rows. I do not want to display this information as the initial procedure is returning own row sets.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can tweak your Store Procedures  by doing something like this .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_StopMessageProc
@StopMsg bit = 0
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @Sql = '';

    SET @Sql = 'SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3....  ';

    IF @StopMsg = 1
         SET @Sql = @Sql + 'INTO #TempDeleteMe';

    SET @Sql = @Sql +     
    'FROM dbo.SomeTable ';

    EXEC(@Sql);
END
GO
```

By defualt your proc will do whatever it does best but when @StopMsg is set to 1 it suppress the return messages/Result sets.

Comment: Should this work if the store procedure returns multiple row sets?

Comment: Well you have to go into the Proc definition and do as above for multiple result sets if @StopMsg = 1 and proc can return multiple result sets, Where ever there is a Select statement in your proc just SELECT * INTO  #Temp table and never call the Temp table in your proc.